# Where can I find a LyX Template that uses an INFORMS-friendly Document Class?

Tags: lyx, templates, lyx-layouts

I'm setting up my local machine (Mac OS 10.11.6) for UI-friendly TEX development with the intention of creating a fast and easy INFORMS paper workflow. FYI, I have a software engineering background).

Things I've done so far:
- Downloaded LyX (LyX-2.2.2+qt5.6.2-x86_64-cocoa.dmg)
- Downloaded TEX (mactex-20161009.pkg)
- Downloaded LaTeX Plugin for Sublime Text 2 and 3
- Downloaded 'Management Science Style Files' from the [INFORMS site](https://www.informs.org/Find-Research-Publications/INFORMS-Journals/Author-Portal/LaTeX-Style-Files)

The sample files contain a 'informs3.cls' document class that I'd like to create a template around in LyX. Can anyone provide insight on how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Imho, you cannot develop a nice and easy UI for (La)TeX to write up fast and easy articles. The results will be of the quality a five yo would produce in daddy's workshop.

Answer (score 1):

You need make a file like  `informs3.layout` to use that class in LyX.

The tutorial to make LyX layouts is in the help menu:

Menu <kbd>Help</kbd> > <kbd>Customization</kbd> > `Chapter 5. Instaling New Document Classes`.

Make a LyX layout is not a trivial task (or at least it is annoying). Unless is already made for someone, or unless you will use that class very frequently, or unless you are a LyX fanatic, my suggestion for non standard classes is just edit a  LaTeX file starting with `\documentclass{informs3} ...`  (with some other editor, not with LyX, obviously) instead of make (a) the LyX layout and (b) the LyX document and (c) several tests an editions of both files to ensure that the layout work as expected.

May be the LaTeX plain text is not so fancy, but .cls files in LaTeX are ready-to-use. `;)`

.